# Make iptables rules persistent after restart

Tags: linux, networking, ports

I'm trying to redirect my port 80 to 8080 because the user need not type the url as webapp:8080 to access the web site.

Here's the command that I came across to redirect from port 80 to 8080 :

```
sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i enp0s25 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

I'm now able to access the page as webapp/. But the problem now I'm facing is that I'm not able to access the page if I give webapp/ after I restart the system.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

"/etc/sysconfig/iptables "  is for centos, you need to find the same file on your linux OS :)

An other solution is to create a conf' file and use this file when the system boot :

- Create a file like "Conf_iptables".
- Add your rules to this file.
- Add execute privilege to root
- `chkconfig Conf_iptables on`

Moreover you have to create 2 iptables rules (for IPv4 and IPv6) if you want to use IPv6 :)

If you need help use this site (sorry but it's in french) : http://blog.sephirots.fr/?p=123

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need is to save iptables rules permanently. It can be various depend on linux distribution.
For Debian/Ubuntu see for instance here:

https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Saving_Iptables_Firewall_Rules_Permanently

Comment: I used service iptables save. That didn't work either after I restarted my system.

Comment: As said above the style can vary from ditribution. Which linux and distro you are using?

Comment: OS is centos, version 7.

Comment: As far as I know CentOS 7 uses FirewallD for iptables setting. With this I am not familirised, but I found this:
https://serverfault.com/questions/626521/centos-7-save-iptables-settings
which is very close to your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I was still facing problems with iptables. So I tried glassfish using proxy configurations : http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.in/2012/07/how-to-port-forward-apaches-80-to.html

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu:
Install `iptables-persistent`. This will create 2 files in /etc/iptables/rules.v4 and rules.v6

Run  `netfilter-persistent save`.

Try rebooting the machine.

Comment: Just a warning to those running Ubuntu Server; DO NOT install `netfilter-persistent` or `iptables-persistent` as it will invariably conflict with UFW and cause critical failures in firewall and corruptions within iptable.